# Is "conda update --all" good enough to upgrade to latest anaconda version?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

The latest anaconda version is 2020.11.

I am using anaconda python 2020.7. Will `conda update --all` be good enough to upgrade my existing version to 2020.11? Are there things that I am missing out if I don't install 2020.11 directly from installation file?

Comment: I find the wording ambiguous. Could you give a more technical phrasing to "*good enough to upgrade*" and "*missing out*"? What comes in the Anaconda installer is what you would get with `conda install anaconda=2020.11`. OTOH, there is no guarantee that `conda update --all` will upgrade to exactly those versions. Most of the time it will upgrade beyond them, but it's also possible that something else you have installed will prevent other packages (or even `anaconda`) from upgrading. So, the answer is more: it depends.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The conda update --all works to update the anaconda package management system, you can also use the conda update anaconda=VersionNumber. For more detailed info check this website
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/

Answer (score 4):

You can easily update Anaconda to the latest version.

Enter these commands:

**conda update conda**

**conda update anaconda=VersionNumber**

Comment: to update to the latest Anaconda version, you do not need to specify the VersionNumber, `conda update anaconda` will automatically update to the latest version

Answer (score -1):

From conda website, you can use conda command to upgrade to latest v2020.11 as of 24Jan2021.
https://www.anaconda.com/blog/individual-edition-2020-11

> You can find the full release notes for Anaconda Individual Edition
> 2020.11 here.
>
> Update to Anaconda 2020.11 now with conda install anaconda=2020.11, or
> download and install Anaconda 2020.11.

So, the right command to run is `conda install anaconda=2020.11`